# ERROR: typer 0.3.2 has requirement click<7.2.0,>=7.1.1, but you'll have click 8.0.3 which is incompatible

Tags: python, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I have requirements.txt file to install python packages

While I do `RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` in Dockerfile I am getting above error

Can anyone explain what it is telling

```
fastapi==0.68.2
uvicorn==0.15.0
nltk==3.6.2
pydantic>=1.2.0,<2.0.0
requests==2.26.0
dill==0.3.4
numpy==1.19.5
spacy==3.1.0
torch==1.9.0
transformers==4.11.3
sentence-splitter==1.4
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Typer is known as [FastAPI of CLIs](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer#fastapi-of-clis).

> Typer stands on the shoulders of a giant. Its only internal dependency is [Click](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer#requirements)

- While installing `fastapi`, it's also installing those dependencies as per requirement.

So to resolve this `ERROR: typer 0.3.2 has requirement click<7.2.0,>=7.1.1, but you'll have click 8.0.3 which is incompatible`, you can try either of the following ways:

1. Try installing a specific click version, `pip install click==7.2.0`

OR

2. Upgrade the typer version to **0.4.0**, `pip install typer==0.4.0`

You can refer to [incompatible click version](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/7160#issuecomment-865453069) and [typer 0.3.2 has requirement click<7.2.0,>=7.1.1, but you have click 8.0.1](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/313#issuecomment-908181587)